# Adding an item to an immutable Seq

Tags: list, scala, seq

Say, I have a sequence of strings as an input and I want to get a new immutable `Seq` which consists of elements of the input and an item `"c"`. Here are two methods that I've discovered to be working:

1. `assert(Seq("a", "b", "c") == Seq("a", "b") ++ Seq("c"))` - the problem with this one is that it seems that instantiating a temporary sequence (`Seq("c")`) just for the sake of the operation is rendundant and will result in overhead
2. `assert(Seq("a", "b", "c") == List("a", "b") ::: "c" :: Nil)` - this one restricts the type of input collection to be a `List`, so `Seq("a", "b") ::: "c" :: Nil` won't work. Also it seems that instantiating a `Nil` may aswell result in overhead

My questions are:

1. Is there any other way of performing this operation?
2. Which one is better?
3. Isn't `Seq("a", "b") ::: Nil` not being allowed a flaw of Scala's developers?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6559996/770361 for `:::` equivalent on non-Lists

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Use the `:+` (append) operator to create a **new** `Seq` using:

```
val seq = Seq("a", "b") :+ "c"
// seq is now ("a","b","c")
```

Note: `:+`  will create a new `Seq` object.
If you have

```
val mySeq = Seq("a","b")
```

and you will call

```
mySeq :+ "c"
```

`mySeq` will still be `("a","b")`

Note that some implementations of `Seq` are more suitable for appending than others. `List` is optimised for prepending. `Vector` has fast append and prepend operations.

`:::` is a method on `List` which requires another `List` as its parameter - what are the advantages that you see in it accepting other types of sequence? It would have to convert other types to a `List`. If you know that `List` is efficient for your use case then use `:::` (if you must). If you want polymorphic behaviour then use the generic `++`.

There's no instantiation overhead to using `Nil`; you don't instantiate it because it's a singleton.