# Append elements to Seq

Tags: scala

I need to append strings to a Seq. I declared the Seq below with `val` as the structure itself is immutable,even though I will change it by adding two elements. I read ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295597/adding-an-item-to-an-immutable-seq)) that the way to append an element to a Seq is with `:+`, and the code compiles fine but it prints an empty list `List()`. How to add elements to a Seq?

```
 val bands = Seq[String]()
 bands :+ "aaa"
 bands :+ "bbb"
 println(bands)
```

Comment: Please first read what's meaning of immutability and how it's handle in programming

Comment: duplicate of [Add element to a list In Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610320/add-element-to-a-list-in-scala) and [Appending an element to the end of a list in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794063/appending-an-element-to-the-end-of-a-list-in-scala)

Comment: The title of the SO question I referred to is misleading [Adding an item to an immutable Seq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295597/adding-an-item-to-an-immutable-seq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:+` function returns a new Sequence, since the default implementation of `Seq` is an immutable `List`.

Try `println((bands :+ "aaa") :+ "bbb")` or `println(bands ++ List("aaa", "bbb"))` instead.

Comment: Read [this](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-idiom-immutable-code-functional-programming-immutability), it should help you understand the concept better and how to apply it.