# What's the difference between `::` and `+:` for prepending to a list)?

Tags: list, scala, operators, prepend, cons

`List` has 2 methods that are specified to prepend an element to an (immutable) list:

- `+:` (implementing `Seq.+:`), and
- `::` (defined only in `List`)

`+:` technically has a more general type signature—

```
def +:[B >: A, That](elem: B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
def ::[B >: A](x: B): List[B]
```

—but ignoring the implicit, which according to the doc message merely requires `That` to be `List[B]`, the signatures are equivalent.

**What is the difference between `List.+:` and `List.::`?** If they are in fact identical, I assume `+:` would be preferred to avoid depending on the concrete implementation `List`. But why was another public method defined, and when would client code call it?

#### Edit

There is also an extractor for `::` in pattern matching, but I'm wondering about these particular methods.

See also: [Scala list concatenation, ::: vs ++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559996/scala-list-concatenation-vs)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The best way to determine the difference between both methods is to look it the source code.

The [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L97) of `::`:

```
def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] =
  new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```

The [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L175) of `+:`:

```
override def +:[B >: A, That](elem: B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That = bf match {
  case _: List.GenericCanBuildFrom[_] => (elem :: this).asInstanceOf[That]
  case _ => super.+:(elem)(bf)
}
```

As you can see, for `List`, both methods do one and the same (the compiler will choose [List.canBuildFrom](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L459) for the `CanBuildFrom` argument).

So, which method to use? Normally one would choose the interface (`+:`) than the implementation (`::`) but because `List` is a general data structure in functional languages it has its own methods which are widely used. Many algorithms are build up the way how `List` works. For example you will find a lot of methods which prepend single elements to `List` or call the convenient `head` or `tail` methods because all these operations are `O(1)`. Therefore, if you work locally with a `List` (inside of single methods or classes), there is no problem to choose the `List`-specific methods. But if you want to communicate between classes, i.e. you want to write some interfaces, you should choose the more general `Seq` interface.

Comment: But why did they expose `List.::` publicly? It looks like they could have implemented everything in `List.+:`, replacing the call to `::` in the first `case` with `new scala.collection.immutable.::(elem, this)`.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I believe it was done so to make it obvious that the algorithm relies on `List` and not on a general `Seq` for the reasons already explained by sschaef. Also, according to [this table](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) there are huge differences on how each `Seq` implementation is intended to be used. For instance `+:` will perform awfully on a `Queue` and using `::` protects you from accidently passing it to your algorithm.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: The Scala community already had some discussions on the sense of `::`. Another point often mentioned is that the existence of `::` has historical reasons. The first versions of Scala did not have such generalized collections as we have today. Furthermore, the `ML` family of functional languages do have `:` as List-prepending operator. Therefore its origin is much deeper as it may look like.

Answer (score 16):

`+:` is more generic, since it allows the result type to be different from the type of the object it is called on. For example:

```
scala> Range(1,4).+:(0)
res7: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 2, 3)
```