# Scala Non-Tail Recursive Solution

Tags: scala, recursion

I have this tail-recursive function that returns true if any element in the list is a `Boolean` value.

```
def anyBoolTailRec[A](test: A=> Boolean, a: List[A]): Boolean = a match {
    case Nil => false
    case h :: t if(!test(h)) => anyBoolTailRec(test, t)
    case _ => true
}
```

The test parameter is just a function to check the values type:

```
def isBool(i: Any) = i match {
    case _: Boolean => true
    case _    => false
}
```

The function is called like this:

```
anyBoolTailRec(isBool, List(1, 2, "hi", "test", false))
>>> true
```

**Question:** How can I turn this tail recursive solution into a non-tail recursive solution? Since we're returning Booleans I'm not sure how to do it.

*Note:* I am aware tail-recursive solutions are better in Scala.

Comment: change second line to `case h :: t if(!test(h)) => val foo = anyBoolTailRec(test, t); foo`
Is the next question going to be how to make it exponential?

Comment: How to make it exponential? No I was just wondering how I could change my function into non-tail solution. The boolean return value was throwing me off. I'm using to doing something like foo(test, t + 1)

Comment: Why are you asking things twice? You already asked about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46598594/scala-tail-recursive-to-not-tail-recursive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to do this.  You're just making your code worse for no benefit, but...

Turning a tail-recursive solution into a non-tail recursive is easy.   You could just add some operation that doesn't affect the result so that the recursive call is no longer in a tail position.  A simple solution that will always work is to store the result of the recursive call in a local variable before returning it.

```
def anyBoolTailRec[A](test: A=> Boolean, a: List[A]): Boolean = a match {
    case Nil => false
    case h :: t if(!test(h)) => val foo = anyBoolTailRec(test, t); foo
    case _ => true
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks. But since we're evaluating false in the second line with `|| false` is there a need for case Nil anymore?

Comment: @Phillip Yes, without the `Nil => false` case, `Nil` would evaluate to true, since it doesn't match the pattern `h :: t` it would fall to the default case `_ => true`.

Comment: @Phillip Dima's comment provides a more general solution that will work for any data type while mine would only work for booleans, I will edit my answer to include his method.