# Difference between ::: and ++ for concatenating Lists

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala list concatenation, ::: vs ++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559996/scala-list-concatenation-vs)

In Scala, say I have two lists

```
scala> val oneTwo = List(1,2)
oneTwo: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

and

```
scala> val threeFour = List(3,4)
threeFour: List[Int] = List(3, 4)
```

I can concatenates Lists by doing:

```
scala> oneTwo ::: threeFour
res30: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Or

```
scala> oneTwo ++ threeFour
res31: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

What is the difference between both approaches?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `:::` method is specific to `List`, while `++` is part of any `Traversable`.

The difference arise out of two things. First, `List` is one of the original Scala collections, used a lot in the compiler, and subject to special optimizations. The `::` concatenation is the same as used in the ML family of languages, one of the big Scala inspirations, and `:::` extrapolates from it.

On the other hand, `++` came along with the redesign of Scala collections on Scala 2.8.0, which made methods and inheritance uniform. I think it existed before that (on `Set`, for example), but the collections did not share a common superclass, so it was basically an ad hoc method for other collections.

In terms of performance, `:::` should beat `++`, but probably not significantly.

Answer (score 6):

From the docs:

> ::: [B >: A](prefix : List[B]) : List[B]
>
> ++ [B >: A](that : Iterable[B]) : List[B]

You can see the `++` works for any `Iterable` while `:::` is specifically for `List`'s

```
scala> val oneTwo = List(1,2)
oneTwo: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> val threeFour = List(3,4)
threeFour: List[Int] = List(3, 4)

scala> val fiveSix = Array(5,6)
fiveSix: Array[Int] = Array(5, 6)

scala> oneTwo ++ fiveSix
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 5, 6)

scala> oneTwo ::: fiveSix
<console>:10: error: value ::: is not a member of Array[Int]
              oneTwo ::: fiveSix
```