# What's the difference between ::: and ++ for Lists?

Tags: list, scala, operators

Given two lists `a` and `b`, what's the difference between `a ::: b` and `a ++ b`? I suspected one of these operators would simply call the other, but in fact, the implementations look completely different:

```
def :::[B >: A](prefix: List[B]): List[B] =
  if (isEmpty) prefix
  else if (prefix.isEmpty) this
  else (new ListBuffer[B] ++= prefix).prependToList(this)

override def ++[B >: A, That](that: GenTraversableOnce[B])
                      (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That = {
  val b = bf(this)
  if (b.isInstanceOf[ListBuffer[_]])(this ::: that.seq.toList).asInstanceOf[That]
  else super.++(that)
}
```

From a usage perspective, should I prefer `a ::: b` or `a ++ b`? From an implementation perspective, is there a specific reason why one of these operators doesn't simply call the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala list concatenation, ::: vs ++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559996/scala-list-concatenation-vs)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is in that you can only use `:::` on 2 lists -- this operation is only available on the `List` datatype. Since lists are sequences, it acts as a concatenation operators for lists.

The `++` method is more general - it allows creating a union of any two collections. That may be two sets, in which case it acts as a union, or two sequences in which case it acts as a concatenation.

There is no semantic difference between `++` and `:::` for 2 lists -- `:::` is the variant of `++` for functional lists that should look more familiar to functional programmers.

The `if` statement you see in the `++` implementation is an optimization -- if both `this` collection and `that` collection are lists, just use the list concatenation operator `:::` to add the two lists together. Otherwise, use the generic implementation of `++` that adds all the elements of `this` and `that` collection to an appropriate builder for the type `That`.

So, the relevant difference for lists is performance -- for functional lists you don't need to traverse the second list as a generic `++` implementation would - only the nodes of the first list need to be reinstantiated to create a new functional list.