# Scala: understanding the ::: operator

Tags: scala

Is it true that applying the `list1 ::: list2` operator to two lists corresponds to appending all of the contents of `list1` to `list2`?

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val b = List(4,5,6)
b: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)

scala> a:::b
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Is there any other use for this operator? I could not find anything on `:::` in the Scala documentation and am wondering the extent of its formal name and use.

Comment: yes seems to be just a list-concetenation - found it: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_lists.htm - and yes it's just that

Comment: Did you look at the [API reference for `List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala list concatenation, ::: vs ++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559996/scala-list-concatenation-vs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is just the list concatenation operator. They are nil terminated linked lists so conceptually all it is really doing is taking the last cons cell of the first list and pointing it to the head of the second list instead of Nil.

You can also use the more generic ++ operator instead of ::: if you prefer. The end result is the same but technically you are making calls on different objects. Operators ending in a : are right associative in Scala so using a ++ b is the same as a.++(b) or basically a.append(b) as opposed to a ::: b being right associative is translated to b.:::(a) which can be read as b.prepend(a).

Comment: This simplification is somewhat disingenuous as it conceals the linear runtime.

Comment: I did not intend to be misleading by not discussing the performance of the current implementation, you make a good point about the performance being surprising to some people.