# The identity for the cons operator in scala

Tags: scala, list, null

Is there any x such that:

```
x :: List(n) == List(n)
```

or

```
x :: List(n, n + 1, n + 2) == List(n, n + 1, n + 2)
```

I thought `Nil` would do this, but it doesn't. It seems to work when I do:

```
n :: Nil
```

or

```
List(n, n + 1, n + 2) :: Nil
```

but I need it the other way around.

Comment: Do you really mean `x :: n == List(n)` in the first example or rather `x :: n == n`?

Comment: it doesn't have to be the cons operator, but I just need some way to append nothing to a List from the left hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `:::` or `++` operator, which will concatenate two lists:

```
Nil ::: List(n)
Nil ++ List(n)
```

Andrey helpfully points out that the `++` operator is more generic, so check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559996/scala-list-concatenation-vs) that he provided in his comment.

Comment: [`::: vs ++`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559996/scala-list-concatenation-vs)

Comment: You should directly include the link in the answer, since the comments might go away at any time.